# Change value of Array elements

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on Exercise 3.35 in C++ Primer Fifth edition ! I've done this exercise using a `while` loop . But when I come to try this exercise using a `for` loop , I couldn't solve  problem of changing an array element value . (I did solve the problem but not using pointers).
**What I need** is that if you can help me solve this exercise to change value of array using **pointers** in a `for` loop.

**Exercise it self**
Using pointers, write a program to set the elements in an array to 0(zero);

**My code with using pointers**

```
int main()
{    
    int arr[] = {1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18};
    int *pbeg = begin(arr);
    int *pend = end(arr);

    while (pbeg != pend)
    {
        pbeg[0]=0;
        ++pbeg;
    }   
    for (auto ii : arr)
    {
        cout<<ii<<" ";
    }
    keep_window_open("~");
    return 0;
}
```

**`for` loop code I've done**

```
int main()
{    
    const size_t ar =10;
    int arr[ar] = {1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ar; ++i)
    {
        arr[i]=0;
    }
    for (auto ii : arr)
    {
        cout<<ii<<" ";
    }
    keep_window_open("~");
    return 0;
}
```

In this `for` loop I haven't used any pointers.

Comment: Arrays are pointers...

Comment: @ColeJohnson: No they are not. They behave very much like pointers, but they are not pointers.

Comment: @ColeJohnson arrays are not pointers but easily decay into pointers.

Comment: So, here's a hint: A while loop and a for loop is very much the same thing, except you initialize a value in the first part, do a condition like in a while in the middle, and update in the third part. You can do almost anything as the "update" part.

Comment: @Borgleader correct. Given a type, `T`, a variable of said type, `var`, and an array offset, `n`, it stands that `var[n]` is the same as `(T)*((char*)var + n * sizeof(T))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    *(pbeg+i) = 0;
}
```

pbeg is your memory address, so you add i to move that many elements forward.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*(pbeg + i * sizeof(int))` considering it is an `int` array? Or does the compiler do that for you?

Comment: For other data types, that'd be correct. `int` simply works because its size coincides with the amount moved forward, though.

Comment: What I said in my previous comment seems to be incorrect: I just tested with gcc and an array of 5 elements was accessed equally well with code just like that regardless of datatype (tested with long, char, int, float, double and a struct containing the aforementioned datatypes).